# Skipping over value when inserting data in Django ORM to avoid duplicate error

Tags: python, django, django-models

My table has a composite key using "unique together" like so

```
class ComponentMap(models.Model):
    key = models.TextField()
    component = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = [['key', 'component']]
        db_table = 'component_map'
```

as you can see this is connected to my postgres table "component_map"

Now this Table is to help figure out if a key has multiple components tied to it.

Since there are thousands of different keys, Whenever someone searches for a key, it will grab all the data from a seperate API and then store it into my database to ensure the data will be there.

The problem I am having is sometimes whenever someone searches for a specific key that is already in the database to see its components it will give an error `duplicate key value violates unique constraint`.

Usually in Django models it will just update the row if there is a duplicate key, but the `unique together` seems to break that functionality.

What i have tried is this:

```
def insert_data(self, data):
    values = list((item['key'],

                   item['name'],

                   list((x['components])for x in item['components']),

                   ) for item in data['issues'])

    for bug in values:
        for x in bug[0]:
            if ComponentMap.objects.filter(key = x):
                continue
            for x in bug[2]:
                c = ComponentMap(key=bug[0],
                                 component=x
                                 )
                c.save()
```

So I thought i could use `continue` to skip over those keys that are already present in the model, But this doesn't seem to work or I am not properly using it.

any help would be appreciated!

EDIT: Why wouldn't this work:

```
for bug in values:
    if ComponentMap.objects.filter(key = bug[0]).exists():
        continue
    for x in bug[2]:
        c = ComponentMap(key=bug[0],
                         component=x,
                         type="Story")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iteration is incorrect, by using `for x in bug[0]` you are going to iterate over the `key` itself, and a string is iterable: you will iterate over the *characters* of the key.

You likely want to insert this like:

```
def insert_data(self, data):
    for item in data['issues']:
        if not ComponentMap.objects.filter(key=item['key']).exists():
            for x in item['components']:
                c = ComponentMap.objects.create(key=key, component=x)
```

We can reduce the number of inserts easily by using a "bulk insert" per key:

```
def insert_data(self, data):
    for item in data['issues']:
        key = item['key']
        if not ComponentMap.objects.filter(key=key).exists():
            ComponentMap.objects.bulk_create(
                [ComponentMap(key=key, component=x) for x in item['components']]
            )
```

Or we can prepare first a list of `ComponentMap` objects, and then make a bulk insert, like:

```
def insert_data(self, data):
    keys = set(ComponentMap.objects.values_list('key', flat=True))
    objs = [
        ComponentMap(key=item['key'], component=x)
        for item in data['issues']
        if item['key'] not in keys
        for x in item['components']
    ]
    ComponentMap.objects.bulk_create(objs)
```

The last one will result in two ORM calls. If the number of components is not that large, it will thus take two queries. If the number of components is larger, it will take more queries, but still quite limited.

Comment: If you look at my edit, `key` `name` and `component_list` are not variables but are iterations of the bigger data set.  In your example I am not able to do  `for item['key'], item['name'] in item in data['issues']`

Comment: That works great, thanks! also if you could, help me understand why my last edit wouldn't work?

Comment: @Mfreeman: it looks like you here accessed the `x['components]` of `item['components']`, so you accessed a "components" key two levels deep.